# How can I link (with New-GPLink) a GPO to Organizational Unit that's encapsulated in another Organizational Unit

Tags: windows, powershell, server, gpo

I'm trying to learn to create GPO with Powershell. I have no issues creating the GPO, set what the GPO does but when I want to link it to Organizational Unit that inside a another Organizational Unit, i cannot find how to do that or even find if it's possible.

[image]

For example, this code works :

```
$GPOObject = New-GPO -Name ’DisableRunMenu’ -Domain ’GPO.local’

New-GPLink -Name ’DisableRunMenu’ -Target ’OU=Testing,DC=GPO,DC=local’
```

That code works, no problem. But How can I link this **GPO** directly to the **Computers OU**?

I have tried `OU=Computers,DC=GPO,DC=local`, not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to specify the full path.

Have you tried 'OU=Computers,OU=Testing,DC=GPO,DC=local' ?

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working! I tried OU=Testing,OU=Computers but not yours, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Computers is a container (CN=Computers   not  OU=Computers)
and you cannot link a GPO to a container, that is the difference between a container and a OU in Active Directory